# Как происходит возврат из функций в c#?

Tags: c#, return

Я понимаю, что  `return` прерывает выполнение функции и возвращает результат. Но куда конкретно вызываемая функция помещает результат перед возвратом управления?

Comment: тут ет особых отличий от других соглашений о вызовах: если помещается в `rax`, то через регистр, иначе копируется в структуру в пред. фрейме стека

Comment: Зависит от разрядности приложения и типа результата, либо в регистры процессора, либо в стек.

Comment: Этот вопрос могут задать на собеседовании, но зачем это знать в обычной жизни - совершенно непонятно. В работе мне ни разу это не понадобилось знать, например. А так ну да - регистры, стек.